# Toggle CSS transition on/off with jQuery mouseover state

Tags: jquery, css, transition

Im trying to stop a "reversing" css transition on un-hovering the element.
I want it to stay on its "forward" postion and when i hover it again it should repeat the "forward" transition and so on.

This i what i have tried:

jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery("#fancy_icon-51-66").mouseleave(function () {
  jQuery(this).removeClass("start-transition");
  jQuery(this).addClass("stop-transition");
});
jQuery("#fancy_icon-51-66").mouseenter(function () {
  jQuery(this).removeClass("stop-transition");
  jQuery(this).addClass("start-transition");
});

});
```

css

```
.stop-transition {

-webkit-transition: none !important;
-moz-transition: none !important;
-o-transition: none !important;
transition: none !important;

}

.start-transition {

-webkit-transition: transform 0.5s !important;
-moz-transition: transform 0.5s !important;
-o-transition: transform 0.5s !important;
transition: transform 0.5s !important;

}
```

The transition itself is a transform -> rotate 360°.

As you might see im a beginner looking for help to achieve this kind of thing.
Thanks for every suggestion!

Comment: go through this link : [ https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition_transform ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
 <div id='element'>HELLO</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #element {position:relative; float:left; width:20%; height:20%; background:#000; border:1px solid #fff; color:#fff; padding:20px; text-align:center;}

 .animate {animation:animated 1s linear;}
 @keyframes animated {
 to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
 }
```

**jQuery (3.4.1)**

```
 $(document).on('mouseenter','#element',function() {
 $('#element').addClass('animate');
 $('#element').on("animationend", function() {
 $('#element').removeClass('animate');
 });
 });
```

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter','#element',function() {
$('#element').addClass('animate');
$('#element').on("animationend", function() {
$('#element').removeClass('animate');
});
});
```

```css
#element {position:relative; float:left; width:20%; height:20%; background:#000; border:1px solid #fff; color:#fff; padding:20px; text-align:center;}

.animate {animation:animated 1s linear;}
@keyframes animated {
to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='element'>HELLO</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w7txpcmk/

Answer (score -1):

**External CSS**

To use the Font Awesome icons, add following line inside the `<head>` section of your HTML page

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

**CSS**

```
div i {
    padding: 10px;
    transition: transform 1.5s !important;
}
    
div i:hover {
    -webkit-transition: transform 1.5s !important;
    -moz-transition: transform 1.5s !important;
    -o-transition: transform 1.5s !important;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

**HTML**

Use following code in `<body>` section of HTML page

```
<div>
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
</div>
```

```css
div i {
  padding: 10px;
  transition: transform 1.5s !important;
}

div i:hover {
  -webkit-transition: transform 1.5s !important;
  -moz-transition: transform 1.5s !important;
  -o-transition: transform 1.5s !important;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
</div>
```